# Using MySqlTransaction to rollback

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C# .NET 3.5 project using MySql 5.1.53 and MySql Connector/Net 6.4.4.

```
'protocol_version', '10'
'version', '5.1.53-community-log'
'version_comment', 'MySQL Community Server (GPL)'
'version_compile_machine', 'unknown'
'version_compile_os', 'Win64'
```

I create a table in my database like this.

```
using (MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection(connection_string))
{
    c.Open();
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand())
    using (MySqlTransaction xt = c.BeginTransaction())
    {
        cmd.Connection = c;
        cmd.Transaction = xt;
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText =
                @"CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
                  ...
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=72 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            throw new System.Exception("This is a simulated failure!!!");

            xt.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            xt.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

But, after the simulated failure the table still exists in my database.

What Do I need to do to make the transaction roll back correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create Table statement causes automatic commit. It doesn't participate in transaction.

See [Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/implicit-commit.html)

> The statements listed in this section (and any synonyms for them)
>   implicitly end a transaction, as if you had done a COMMIT before
>   executing the statement.

In your case you can just drop the table if an exception occurs. Its not technically a rollback but it should serve your purpose.

Btw you don't need a try catch block. Transaction is rolled back automatically if dispose is called on it without calling Commit

Comment: Removing the try/catch block did not help

Comment: What's the best way to roll back a create? Just drop the tables if there is an exception?

Comment: @PaulH yea. Dropping the table is the only option.

Comment: @Hasan - The dispose is also called because of the using statements.

Comment: I was trying to get proof of this statement "Transaction is rolled back automatically if dispose is called on it without calling Commit". The proof can be found in source download from mysql.com mysqlconnector-6.5.4\Source\MySql.Data\transaction.cs Dispose() method.